# Split web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a web.config file which is split already to have ipSecurity  in a separate file. This file hold all the blocked ip's by country.
The problem is that web.security file is still to large and i get this error

> Cannot read configuration file because it exceeds the maximum file
>   size

Question is can i split the web.security file into multiple files? (I am on a shared hosting so can't increase file limit size)

below is the config section:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity configSource="web.security"></ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This may be a hint that you should not be using an XML file to keep those blocked IP addresses. Maybe use a database. How are you _managing_ so many blocked addresses? What do you do when you find that one address should no longer be blocked?

Comment: @John Saunders i deliberately block entire country ip range (it is about 2-3k entries), single ip can be allowed as well if needed, but no need. Important thing is that this is done on IIS level so no request is coming through to my website. However If ill do it using db the request has to come through and i'll have to process the ip against db.

Comment: Sounds like you need to (start) thinking of (at least) a network firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done this but in theory you should be able to use multiple config files and add them to the current configuration programmatically:

```
void InitIpSecurityConfig()
  {
    var pathArray = new[] { "path1", "path2", "pathN" };

    foreach (var path in pathArray)
      {
        var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(path);
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationLevel.None);

        // manipulate and save to current XML config file
      }
   }
```

Good luck!